# apache 2.4 serverAlias with * wildcard overwrittes specificed vhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost, apache2.4

I have two vhosts the default one and another one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.eve-stuff.com
    ServerAlias *.eve-stuff.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
    <Directory /var/www/html/test>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        #Require all denied
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This one should just redirect all subdomains that a not specifically setup to the test directory.
This is another vhost i have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.eve-stuff.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev 
        <Directory /var/www/html/dev>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This one should show the dev folder for the dev subdomain.

From what I understood from the apache doc the `ServerAlias *.eve-stuff.com` in the first host will always catch UNLESS another vhost has  specifically been created for the address.

However `dev.eve-stuff.com` still redirects to the test folder not to the dev folder, as it should.

All dns entries, also for the subdomains, point to the right IP.
I am running Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu).

Comment: Why don't you change the second one to: <VirtualHost dev.eve-stuff.com:80>?

Comment: You put an IP address in the VirtualHost-directive, not a domain

Comment: You may be right , I can't find examples backing my comment I'll check it but I have my dev env setup like this and it works. I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I also have NameVirtualHost *:80 at the begining of my virtual hosts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the order in which it is setup matters.
Apache apparently looks for the matching host it can find.
Since the first config was in `000-default.conf` and the second one was in the `020-dev.conf` the dev-subdomain matched the first vhost and used that.
I changed default to `999-default.conf` which means now dev will first be matched with the proper vhost but other undefined subdomains will still be matched with the default vhost.

Comment: I would probably suggest turning off `000-default.conf` with `a2dissite 000-default.conf` if you've got a catch-all config in `020-dev.conf`, because that is only really there to outline what features are available.